# TLE in BFS approach for SPOJ AKBAR

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

My approach is to do a BFS from soldier source till its strength. However, I am getting TLE. I found on some post that the reason might be memset but I can't figure it  Here's the ideone link http://ideone.com/ljgRhi or the complete code below

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define fio ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0) 
#define FOR(i, a, b) for(int i = a;i < b; i++)      
#define rev(i, a, b) for(int i = a;i > b; i--)      
#define si(a)   scanf("%d", &a)                     
#define pi(a)   printf("%d\n", a)                   
typedef long long ll;                               //W
#define pb push_back                                //E
#define ff first                                        //A
#define ss second                                   //K
#define MOD (ll)1000000007
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#define N 1000005
#define EPS 1e-12
template <typename T> T gcd(T a, T b){return (b==0)?a:gcd(b,a%b);}
using namespace std;

vector<ll> g[N];
bool f[N]={0};
bool curr[N]={0};
//bool sold[N]={0};


bool solve(ll a, ll b)
{
    memset(curr, 0, sizeof(curr));
    if(f[a])
        return 0;

    queue<pair<ll, ll> > q;
    q.push({a, b});
    f[a]=1;
    curr[a] = 1;
    ll v, h;

    while(!q.empty())
    {

        v = q.front().ff;
        h = q.front().ss;
        q.pop();
        if(h>0)
        {
            for(auto w:g[v])
            {
                if(!curr[w])
                {
                    if(f[w])
                        return 0;

                    curr[w]=1;
                    f[w]=1;
                    q.push({w, h-1});
                }

            }
        }   
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    fio;
    ll t, n, r, m;
    cin>>t;

    while(t--)
    {
        pair<ll, ll> p; 
        cin>>n>>r>>m;
        while(r--)
        {
            ll x,y;
            cin>>x>>y;
            g[y].pb(x);
            g[x].pb(y);
        }

        vector<pair<ll, ll> > as;
        while(m--)
        {
            ll x,y;
            cin>>x>>y;
            //sold[x] = 1;
            p = {x, y};
            as.pb(p);
        }

        bool fl;
        for(auto i:as)
        {
            fl = solve(i.ff, i.ss);
            if(!fl)
                {cout<<"No\n"; break;}
        }
        if(fl)      
        {
            for(ll i=1;i<=n;i++)
            if(!f[i])
            {
                fl=0;
                cout<<"No\n"; 
                break;
            }
        }
        if(fl) cout<<"Yes\n";

        //clear
        for(ll i=0;i<=n;i++)
            g[i].clear();
        //as.clear();
        memset(f, 0, sizeof(f));
        //memset(sold, 0, sizeof(sold));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think unnecessary copying is a more likely culprit.

Comment: @molbdnilo I didn't get you.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid unnecessary copying, each node will be explored completely if and only if it can be reached by some solider's strength, so when another soldier reaches an area which was already explored, it means there are two guards protecting that area, which is not optimal.

Here's the [link](https://gist.github.com/Kishy-nivas/87e47303a6ec992870a163e57945869d) for the accepted code(C++)